# Каким способом можно загрузить txt-файл в вк и отправить его?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

У меня есть файл который автоматически наполняется информацией и сохраняется по пути `"C:\\полный путь до папки\\tempfiles\\{автоматически генерируемое название файла}.txt"` в названии файла обычно получается это `"chat_{chatId}_{date}.txt"`

Код:

```
//до этого идет полная генерация текста файла, далее идет создание файла при помощи fs.writeFileSync    
var fs = require('fs');
let path = "./tempfiles/" + "chat_" + message.chatId + "_" + getCurrentTimeFON()
let path2 = "\\tempfiles\\" + "chat_" + message.chatId + "_" + getCurrentTimeFON()
fs.writeFileSync(path, text, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
let fileNaming = "chat_" + message.chatId + "_" + getCurrentTimeFON() + ".txt"
```

Мне нужно этот файлик отправить как сообщение но при отправке методом `vk.upload.messageDocument` (см код ниже) выходит ошибка 404 при нажатии на сам файл, но файл при этом в самом вк отображается, указывается его вес и название.

Код:

```
await vk.upload.messageDocument({
    peer_id: message.peerId,
    source: {
        value: "C:\\{полный путь до папки}\\" + path2,
        filename: fileNaming,
        contentType: "text/plane"
    }
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    vk.api.messages.edit({ peer_id: message.peerId, conversation_message_id: message.conversationMessageId+ 1, message: `Файл:`, attachment: response, })
})
```

Также прикладываю функцию `getCurrentTimeFON()`:

```
function getCurrentTimeFON() {
    const now = new Date();
    
    const day = String(now.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const month = String(now.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const year = now.getFullYear();
    
    const hours = String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    const minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    
    const formattedTime = `${day}${month}${year}`;
    
    return formattedTime;
}
```

То что находится в файлике:

```
-----------------------------------------------

История сообщений за последние 24 часа;

-----------------------------------------------

Сообщение от "****************************************"
Текст: 123
Время отправки: 18.12.2023 10:43:45

-----------------------------------------------

Всего сообщений: 1;

-----------------------------------------------
```

Прикладываю полезные ссылки и также немного о том что я использую:

vk-io

@vk-io/hear

Откуда я взял `vk.upload.messageDocument`? https://github.com/negezor/vk-io/tree/master/packages/vk-io/src/upload

Также в коментариях вы можете спросить о каком то куске кода или о более обширной информации.